# How to Optimize for Windowed Aggregate Partition-By Clause in Netezza

Tags: netezza

I have a 10 billion row FACT table in netezza and I want to perform ROW_NUMBER() ,MAX () over and SUM () over in one query . When I am doing the same query executes for more than 3 hours . is there any way to improve the query performance .Table is distributed on the 4 columns which are part of the partition clause (COLA,COLB,COLC,COLD).

For sample example

```
SUM(STR_QTY) OVER (
                PARTITION BY 
                 COLA
                ,COLB
                ,COLC
                ,COLD
                ) AS SLS_RTRN_QTY
,
SUM(STR_QTY_1) OVER (
                PARTITION BY 
                 COLA
                ,COLB
                ,COLC
                ,COLD
                ) AS VAL_QTY
,MIN(ITM_FST_DT) OVER (
                PARTITION BY COLA
                ,COLB
                ) AS FIRST_DT
,MAX(ITM_LST_DT) OVER (
                PARTITION BY PARTITION BY COLA
                ,COLB
                ) AS LAST_DT
```

Edit 1: Original query

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (
    SELECT F.DT_KEY AS DT_KEY
        ,F.COL_KEY AS COL_KEY
        ,F.PCK_ITM_KEY AS PCK_ITM_KEY
        ,F.COLC AS COLC
        ,F.COLD AS COLD
        ,F.COLA AS COLA
        ,F.COLB AS COLB
        ,F.COLC AS COLC
        ,F.SH_QTY AS SH_QTY
        ,SUM(F.SLS_QTY) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.COLD
            ,F.COLA
            ,F.COLB
            ,F.COLC
            ) AS SLS_QTY
        ,SUM(F.SLS_RTRN_QTY) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.COLD
            ,F.COLA
            ,F.COLB
            ,F.COLC
            ) AS SLS_RTRN_QTY
        ,SUM(F.PCHSE_QTY) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.COLD
            ,F.COLA
            ,F.COLB
            ,F.COLC
            ) AS PCHSE_QTY

        ,MAX(F.LST_ML_DT) OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.COLA
            ,F.COLC
            ) AS LST_ML_DT
        ,F.LST_MODFD_DTTM AS LST_MODFD_DTTM
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY F.COLD
            ,F.COLA
            ,F.COLB
            ,F.COLC
            ,F.COLE ORDER BY F.DT_KEY DESC
            ) AS RNK
    FROM FCT_ITEM F
    ) a
WHERE a.RNK = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will cause the entire table to be redistributed on COLA and COLB. If the set of distribution columns is a subset of the partition columns then you won't haven't the expensive redistribution.

As a general rule, use the fewest columns possible in your distribution clause while still maintaining a fairly even distribution. 
If just COLA or COLB alone would given even distribution then go with one of those.

Comment: I have seen strange behavior with our machine lately . This query used to run fine (~1Hr) when system was at 70% full . IS there any link between growing data query performance . Currently Netezza system has reached its capacity storage wise (with our current license of 50% ) .

Comment: If you mean that you have a Growth-on-Demand system where you are only entitled to 50% of the storage capacity, that is not a hard limit enforced by the system.  However, when you have redistribute the whole table to answer a query, that causes a lot of temporary, usually unnecssary write/read pressure on the system, as it will be moving billions of rows around amongst the SPUs to answer the question.  So data growth can definitely be an issue

Comment: When there is a table with 4 distribution columns, 9 times out of 10, that was a mistake and should be re-evaluated.

Comment: I tried to change the distribution but didnt help . Updated original query.